# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager POST request fails with network connection was lost (-1005)

Tags: ios, objective-c, django, http-post

my server side is google compute engine with DJango services as API

this is the code I'm running in xcode IOS 6.1

```
static NSString *const BaseURLString = @"http://myUrl/";

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:BaseURLString
   parameters:[self getParameters]
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          NSArray *returnedData = (NSArray *)responseObject;
          [self doSomething:returnedData];
      }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Properties" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          [av show];
      }];
```

It always fails with `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."` but when I call the service from the terminal using `curl -datacurl --data "param1=1&param2=3" http://myUrl/` it works perfect

Comment: how to solved this issue ?

Comment: @kirtimali I still don't know, maybe if you add +1 to the question someone will decide to answer it.

Comment: I have the same question, it fails for one particular request, but not the rest of them

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString];
```

and instead of

```
   [manager POST:BaseURLString parameters:[self getParameters]
  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      NSArray *returnedData = (NSArray *)responseObject;
      [self doSomething:returnedData];
```

use

```
   [manager POST:url parameters:[self getParameters]
  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      NSArray *returnedData = (NSArray *)responseObject;
      [self doSomething:returnedData];
```